# Node callback firing at the same time

Tags: javascript, node.js

Consider [this](http://debuggable.com/posts/understanding-node-js:4bd98440-45e4-4a9a-8ef7-0f7ecbdd56cb):

> there can only be one callback firing at the same time

So consider this code:

```
var http = require("http"); 
function onRequest(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello World");
  response.end();
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
```

If my application receives a request then OnRequest is called.
If it's only possible to fire one call back at a time then the requests are queued. Is it right?

Comment: What are you trying to figure out? Requests are always queued at the operating system level anyway.

Comment: Node is not a multi-threaded environment.

Comment: @Pointy Even I had the same doubt. Can you please point me to some doc s?

Comment: @thefourtheye Node is a single-threaded wrapper around V8.

Comment: @Pointy I know node is single-thread please read again my question

Comment: The answer is **yes**, requests are queued.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Node.js is designed in such a way that when request arrives it gives the info to callback function and let it handle it and main process waits for next request.

so if you set setTimeout in  onRequest to 10 sec. and make 100 request to server all the request will return you the data after 10 sec not 10,20,30 ...

As node.js is single process application the request will be queued but human thats for very small fraction of time. You can try experimental features such as http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html to handle request in parallel. Here queuing does not mean that unless reques1 get answered request2 will not be answered but it means that node process will quesing them untill every earlier request gets their callbacks assigned that do not effect your websites performance at all.

read http://book.mixu.net/node/single.html it is one of the most awesome books also
     http://www.nodebeginner.org/

**EDIT 1**
Node.js request you to write non-blocking code. In case of none blocking code we use callbacks.

Node.js is single threaded application but it behaves like one main important thread and other less-important thread pool.(there are no specific priorities as such).

```
Eg: An ambulance waits for phone call to come every time. 
    when it gets a call it goes to pick up the patient and take him to the hospital.
    while the doctor is performing operation on the patients. Ambulance team does not 
    switch off their phone and wait for its first patient to get healthy but 
    If they get another call they go to pick up the next guy

    when they were off to receive next guy hospital calls and say first patient is
    healthy and drop him home, ambulance does not leave other guy in pain but complete
    its second task and then drop first guy home.

    so callback was doctorPerformOperation which was put in thread pool
    and
    recieveTheGuy was a blocking operation
```

So from your code it is very small so it might happen that every response might be after its request but it is also a possibility that out of 5 (almost) simultaneous requests 3rd gets callback assigned before 2nds connection's last 'ack'.

**More specific examples**

**Blocking code**

```
 setTimeout(function() {
   console.log('bye')
 }, 100);

 while(1) {
 }
```

'bye' will never be printed

**None Blocking code**

```
 setTimeout(function() {
   console.log('bye')
 }, 100);

 setInterval(function() {
   console.log('hi');
 }, 100);
```

bye will be printed after .1 sec but it can be delayed by some nano second if hi were printing at the same instance.

It executes the callbacks when main process is free.

**More non-blocking**

```
setTimeout(function() {
   console.log('bye')
 }, 100);

 setInterval(function() {
   console.log('hi');
 }, 50);

setInterval(function(){
   console.log('hello');
},100);
```

Guess,what will happen with this?

**EDIT 2:**

I wrote a small code

```
exports.sample = function (res) {
var tcpsocket = net.createConnection(port, host);
tcpsocket.on('connect', function () {
    tcpsocket.write('query');
    console.log('tcp');
});
tcpsocket.on('data', function (data) {
    res.write(data);
});
tcpsocket.on('end', function () {
    console.log('end');
    res.end();
});
tcpsocket.on('error', function (e) {
   var ret={error:'error'}
   res.end(JSON.stringify(ret));
   console.log('Error occured in tcp socket');
       console.log(e);
});
tcpsocket.on('close', function () {
    console.log('socket close');
    res.end();
});
};
```

Now the socket I was connecting to was a c socket which writes the data in 10 sec interval 10 times. So each request takes around 100s to finish. as I did not call res.end in 'data' event the browser does not load anything untill full request is completed. If you want to see the data coming in realtime you can use curl for the same url.

Result: When you open 10 tabs same time you will be able to see the data in all tabs in 100sec (not 100s,200s...)

Comment: see this:The event could be from an HTTP client connection, or perhaps from a file read. Since there is only one process, there is no parallel execution of Javascript code. Even though you may have several evented I/O operations with different callbacks ongoing, only one of them will have it's Node/Javascript code run at a time (the rest will be activated whenever they are ready and no other JS code is running).

Comment: No there is no parallel code but its running using time multiplexing, what author said is correct-still he means that no request get blocked unless some call is blocking example while loop.

Comment: Wht is this:nly one of them will have it's Node/Javascript code run at a time.So my requests are queued.

Comment: Of course if you run multiple instances of node on a multicore machine or across several machines, JavaScript code can run in parallel!